# Чем отличаются override и new

Tags: c#

Да я знаю, что override переопределяет virtual, а new затеняет, но чем они отличаются на практике? Пример

```
class A { public void DoSomeStuff(){} }

class B : A { public new void DoSomeStuff(){} }
```

Здесь я затенил, но если я захочу вызвать A.DoSomeStuff я могу просто обратиться к base.
С другой стороны, если бы я использовал virtual и override, то чтобы вызвать переопределеный метод мне всеравно пришлось бы использовать base. В чем разница?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Разница проявляется в случае полиморфизма. Если вы работаете с экземпляром класса-наследника через его родительский класс, то в случае, если вы будете вызывать переопределенный виртуальный метод (override), то будет вызвана его реализация из наследника, а если перекрытый (new), то будет вызван метод базового класса.
Нагляднее будет увидеть на примере:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Base derivedAsBase = new Derived();

            derivedAsBase.First();  // Derived.First(), выведет "First from Derived"                
            derivedAsBase.Second(); // Base.Second(), выведет "Second from Base"

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Base
    {
        public virtual void First()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First from Base");
        }

        public virtual void Second()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Second from Base");
        }
    }

    class Derived : Base
    {
        public override void First()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First from Derived");
        }

        public new void Second()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Second from Derived");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Разница в использовании.
когда вы как клиент (не знающий о его внутренностях) используете класс B:

```
var b = new B();
b.DoSomething();
```