# Проблема реализации наследования

Tags: c#

Есть интерфейс `interface ITransport`, с описанием метода `void Show();`

Этот интерфейс реализует абстрактный класс

`abstract class Naz_Transport:ITransport` и соответственно метод `public void Show(){}`.

Есть класс, который наследуется от выше описанного класса

`class Avtobus:Naz_Transport` и в нем также есть метод

```
new public void Show()
{
    base.Show();
    + еще некоторые данные, принадлежащие этому классу
}
```

Проблема следующая, в мэйне создаю массив объектов

```
ITransport[] arr = { new Avtobus(тут данные для конструктора) };
```

И когда пытаюсь вызвать метод `arr[0].Show();` почему то срабатывает метод из класса  `Naz_Transport`, хотя мне нужно, что бы срабатывал метод из класса `Avtobus`.

Что не так делаю? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: ничего непонятно. но вы сами вызываете базовый метод `base.Show();`

Comment: Всё верно, но вдобавок к нему, я хочу вывести еще одну строку (данные из класса Avtobus), они не выводятся. Но если я в мейне создаю просто объект класса Avtobus, то всё в порядке, а вот когда с помощью массивов объектов интерфейса - не получается.

Comment: аааа, теперь понятно, проблема в `new public` - используйте [`override`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) и все заработает

Comment: Действительно заработало, а почему нельзя было сделать так, как сделал я?

Comment: [Чем отличаются override и new](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/246425/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-override-%D0%B8-new)

Comment: @Grundy, Вы у Александра научились ответ в комментариях давать? Дайте человеку нормальный ответ, чтобы он его принял.

Comment: @ixSci, так-то я отметил как дубликат :) не знаю почему еще 4 человека не поддерживают :)

Comment: @Grundy, на мой взгляд не дубликат, всё же. Я бы свёл Ваши комментарии в ответ, в котором, в том числе, будет и ссылка на отличие `new` и `override`

Comment: @ixSci, готово :-) но похоже опоздал чуть с ответом :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в `new public` - используйте [`override`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) и все заработает.

---

Как написано в MSDN в руководстве: [Использование ключевых слов "Override" и "New"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173153.aspx)

> В C# метод в производном классе может иметь то же имя, что и метод в базовом классе.Можно задать способ взаимодействия методов, воспользовавшись ключевыми словами [`new`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/51y09td4.aspx) и [`override`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ebca9ah3.aspx). Модификатор `override` расширяет метод базового класса, а модификатор `new` скрывает его.

Основная разница между данными ключевыми словами заметна при приведении объекта к базовому классу.

Если рассматривать пример из вопроса:

1. Базовый класс реализует интерфейс
2. Наследник перекрывает метод базового класса
3. Объекты хранятся в массиве интерфейсов

Так как интерфейс в данном случае реализует только базовый класс, помещение объекта в массив равносильно приведению его к базовому классу.

Таким образом  работают правила аналогичные случаю

```
Base a = new Derived();
a.Show();
```

И в случае с использованием `new` вызовется функция базового класса.

Стоит заметить, что если интерфейс будет реализовывать и класс наследник, то такой проблемы не возникло бы, так как при приведении к интерфейсу не было бы приведения к базовому классу.

Пример с различными вариантами объявления

```
public static class Program
{
    interface IA
    {
        void Show();
    }
    class A : IA
    {
        public virtual void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
    }
    class B : A
    {
        new public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
    }
    class C : A
    {
        override public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C");
        }
    }
    class D : A,IA
    {
        new public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("D");
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        IA[] ia = new IA[] { new B(), new C(), new D() };
        foreach (var i in ia)
        {
            i.Show();
        }
    }
    /*
      Выведет:
      A
      C
      D
    */
}
```