# Доступ к данным производного класса через базовый при upcast'е

Tags: c#, ооп

```
class BaseClass
{
    private string[] baseArray = null;

    // Конструктор.
    public BaseClass()
    {
        baseArray = new string[3];
        baseArray[0] = "Ноль";
        baseArray[1] = "Один";
        baseArray[2] = "Два";
    }

    // Виртуальный индексатор.
    public virtual string this[int index]
    {
        get { return baseArray[index]; }
    }
}


class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    private string[] derivedArray = null;


    // Конструктор.
    public DerivedClass()
    {
        derivedArray = new string[3];
        derivedArray[0] = "Zero!";
        derivedArray[1] = "One!";
        derivedArray[2] = "Two!";
    }

    // Переопределенный индексатор.
    public override string this[int index]
    {
        get { return base[index] + " - " + derivedArray[index]; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DerivedClass instance = new DerivedClass();
        BaseClass instance1 = instance;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(instance1[i]);

        }

        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Я создаю объект instance ,класса  DerivedClass, который в свою очередь наследуется от BaseClass.Потом создаю ещё один объект instance1 класса BaseClass и присваиваю ему объект instance.

```
BaseClass instance1 = instance;
```

Я так понимаю, что на этом моменте происходит Upcast и теперь объекту instance1 недоступны данные класса DerrivedClass.Но при этом, вызывая из объекта instance1 переопределённый индексатор, я обращаюсь к данным производного класса.

```
get { return base[index] + " - " + derivedArray[index]; }
```

Как тогда такое обращение к данным производного класса вообще возможно, если базовому классу вообще ничего неизвестно о производном ?

Comment: _Как тогда такое обращение к данным производного класса вообще возможно?_ - все из-за `public virtual` и `public override`

Comment: `Потом создаю ещё один объект instance1 класса BaseClass и присваиваю ему объект instance.` - Нет! Вы просто копируете "ссылку" на объект в еще одну переменную!

Comment: `Я так понимаю, что на этом моменте происходит Upcast и теперь объекту instance1 недоступны данные класса DerrivedClass.` - Нет! В самом объекте хранится информация о его типе!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Чем отличаются override и new](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/246425/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-override-%d0%b8-new)

Comment: Вам нужно почитать про ООП еще. `Как тогда такое обращение к данным производного класса вообще возможно, если базовому классу вообще ничего неизвестно о производном ?` Полиморфизм же! Вот это почитайте хотя бы: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.19.php

Answer (score 2):

Это и есть суть полиморфизма - вы переопределяете в наследнике виртуальные методы предка (либо реализуете абстрактные), и когда выполняете upcast наследника к предку, то при вызове методов предка получите реализацию, выполненную в наследнике.  Не случайно в вашем коде индексатор объявлен с модификатором `virtual`, а в наследнике переопределён с помощью `override`? что позволяет делать такое нехитрое "колдунство"