# Полиморфизм модификаторы new и virtual/override

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему вызов метода с модификатором new не является полиморфным, а с модификаторами virtual/override является?

Comment: Ну это скорее вопрос к разработчикам языка

Comment: Попробуйте объявить объект дочернего типа через базовый тип и вызвать переопределяемый метод, увидите разницу (если я правильно понял вопрос)

Comment: Для того, чтобы при разработке класса можно было четко определить, какие члены должны быть неизменной, а какие следует считать "черным ящиком". Без этой возможности сложные задачи нельзя упростить. Даже в таких языках как JavaScript (которые позволяют переопределить вообще все методы объекта), и то прибегают к конвенциям (договариваются, например, что функции с нижним подчеркиванием менять никак нельзя). Чтобы была хоть какая-то стабильная основа.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос на **понимание** теории, поэтому постараюсь ответить просто, но понятно.

Полиморфизм - это одинаковое, по своей сути, поведение, но реализуемое поразному.

В C# принцип полиморфизма реализуется с помощью виртуальных методов и переопределения (`override`) их в наследниках.

`new` предназначен для тех случаев, когда мы не можем менять код базового класса, а нужный нам метод не является виртуальным и его поведение нам не подходит. Иными словами: когда нельзя, но очень хочется. Такой метод не является полиморфным просто потому, что он не является частью общего интерфейса базового класса. Это просто какой-то другой метод класса наследника, не имеющий ни какого отношения к базовому классу, но мы очень хотим, чтобы у него была сигнатура как у одного из методов базового класса.

Примеры тут, разумеется, уже [были](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/246440/198316), но пусть уж будет все в одном месте.

Возьмем для примера птиц, все птицы имеют название и могут перемещаться в пространстве, поэтому мы можем создать такой базовый класс:

```
abstract class Bird
{
    public virtual string Name => "Птица";
    public void Move() { Console.WriteLine($"{Name} летит"); }
}
```

Свойство Name сразу сделали виртуальным, ведь название то у каждой птички свое, а метод Move оставили обычным, большинство ведь летает, а у исключений перекроем потом, делов-то.

Теперь мы хотим разнообразить наш зоопарк и заводим производные классы переопределив свойство Name

```
class Eagle : Bird 
{
    public override string Name => "Орёл"; 
}

class Ostrich : Bird
{
    public override string Name => "Страус"; 
    //и тут вспоминаем, что страус не летает, а бегает
    new void Move() { Console.WriteLine($"{Name} бежит"); }
}

class Penguin : Bird 
{
    public override string Name => "Пингвин";
    //а пингвин и бегает с трудом, зато плавает
    new void Move() { Console.WriteLine($"{Name} плывет"); }
}
```

Вроде все хорошо, все учли. Собираем зоопарк в кучу:

```
Bird[] birds = {new Eagle(), new Ostrich(), new Penguin()};
```

И выводим на прогулку:

```
foreach(Bird b in birds)
{
    b.Move();
}
```

и выясняем интересный факт, с именами все нормально, но внезапно все научились летать:

> Вывод в консоль в результате выполнения цикла:
>   Орёл летит
>   Страус летит
>   Пингвин летит

`Name` у нас было виртуальным, поэтому работает полиморфизм и несмотря на то, что переменная у нас базового класса Bird, получаем то, что хотели получить - у каждой птички свое имя.

`Move` не был виртуальным, мы просто скрыли его базовую реализацию под новым методом класса-наследника. В этом случае полиморфизм не работает и при обращении через переменную базового класса вызывается базовая реализация метода. Поэтому сами по себе страусы у нас как положено бегают, пингвины плавают, а в компании с другими птицами могут и полетать, даже если крылья вообще не предусмотрены природой, как у Киви. =)

Comment: @rdom что вы имеете в виду под "поведением" (класс, объект, метод базового класса, сигнатура метода или что-то другое) и "реализацией"?

Comment: @Alex_ Класс - описание объекта, его структуры (поля) и поведения (методы). Реализация - это внутренности (код) метода, их может и не быть, если метод абстрактный. Сигнатура метода - просто некое уникальное описание, которое позволяет отличить один метод от другого.